# angular two-way binding not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to build a small application using angular (i just started learning it). The app contains a form and [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) WYSIWYG editor. I am trying to connect the form to the editor using `ng-model` and `ng-bind` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```js
let app = angular.module('tempApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = " "
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="tempApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="main">
  <!-- Initialize the editor. -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#editarea').froalaEditor()
    });
  </script>

  <input autofocus ng-model="text">

  <!--Editor Area-->
  <div id="editarea">
    <p>{{text}}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you imported all the jquery stuff and code?

Comment: yes i have imported everything, i just excluded it from the snippet

Comment: use angular floala https://github.com/froala/angular-froala